# Teamviewer, can I prevent anyone who connects to my machine via Teamviewer, from accessing my local network? How can I do that

Tags: windows-7, vpn, windows-10, teamviewer

I run Windows 10 and run a Teamviewer instance on this machine. The machine is on a local network to which other local machines connect as well. How can I make sure that users who connect to my machine (that has Teamviewer installed on it) can access this machine but not other machines on the same local network?

Is there any setting or policy where I can restrict or completely prevent access to the local network for any TeamViewer connected clients?

Comment: A possibility could be to set up a new user for the visitors. Set it so they can't access network locations.

Comment: @codeSwift4Life, how would I set it so that a visitor/user cannot access network locations?